# API JSON response using ng-repeat in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, api, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm having a weird issue using ng-repeat on the JSON response from the Google PageSpeed API. Basically, I have it working BUT it is oddly returning an odd BLANK UL before followed by the correct reply.

**Test page**: http://staging.converge.io/test-json

**My controller**: *(will change the API key once this gets answered)*

```
function FetchCtrl($scope, $http, $templateCache) {
    $scope.method = 'GET';
    $scope.url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v1/runPagespeed?url=http://www.web.com&key=AIzaSyA5_ykqZChHFiUEc6ztklj9z8i6V6g3rdc';
    $scope.key = 'AIzaSyA5_ykqZChHFiUEc6ztklj9z8i6V6g3rdc';
    $scope.strategy = 'mobile';

    $scope.fetch = function() {
        $scope.code = null;
        $scope.response = null;

        $http({method: $scope.method, url: $scope.url + '&strategy=' + $scope.strategy, cache: $templateCache}).
        success(function(data, status) {
            $scope.status = status;
            $scope.data = data;
        }).
        error(function(data, status) {
            $scope.data = data || "Request failed";
            $scope.status = status;
        });
    };

    $scope.updateModel = function(method, url) {
        $scope.method = method;
        $scope.url = url;
    };
}
```

**HTML**:

```
            <ul ng-repeat="formattedResult in data.formattedResults">
                <li ng-repeat="ruleResult in formattedResult">
                    <h4>{{ruleResult.localizedRuleName}}</h4>
                    <strong>Impact score</strong>: {{ruleResult.ruleImpact*10 | number:0}}
                </li>
            </ul>
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see in the response, `formattedResults` is not an array, it's an object containing an array of `ruleResults`. You need to change the way you access your data.

Replace:

```
<ul ng-repeat="formattedResult in data.formattedResults">
            <li ng-repeat="ruleResult in formattedResult">
                <h4>{{ruleResult.localizedRuleName}}</h4>
                <strong>Impact score</strong>: {{ruleResult.ruleImpact*10 | number:0}}
            </li>
        </ul>
```

With

```
<ul>
     <li ng-repeat="ruleResult in data.formattedResults.ruleResults">
             <h4>{{ruleResult.localizedRuleName}}</h4>
             <strong>Impact score</strong>: {{ruleResult.ruleImpact*10 | number:0}}
     </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This didn't work but rather results in a different rendering issue with duplicating results twice (I updated my test page..

Comment: @Joe Conlin: I don't know what you expect when you use `ng-repeat="formattedResult in data.formattedResults"`. Because `data.formattedResults` is an OBJECT, by using `in`, you're iterating all object PROPERTIES (ruleResults, and locale). That's why it's duplicated twice. Check my answer, I did not have `ng-repeat="formattedResult in data.formattedResults"` in <ul>

Comment: You are correct, I missed that. Your answer worked perfectly. Thanks!